# I want to create a 2D vector with each index being a vector of int

Tags: c++, vector

I want my data structure to look something like this when populated:

```
[[1, 2, 3] [3, 3, 3] [4, 4, 4]]
[[5, 4, 5] [3, 4, 5] [3, 3, 3]]
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I've tried doing:

```
vector<vector<vector<int> > > x;
```

But I'm having trouble populating it. I think it's basically a matrix of vectors? I'm just not sure how to go about it.

EDIT: Sorry, I should've specified a bit more.

The core functionality of my program is to create multiple vector of size 3 and push them 1 by 1 in a 30x3 matrix of vectors. The matrix will be initially completely empty.

I want to be able to push a vector at a specific row, similar to something like this

```
vector<int> y{1, 2, 3};
x.at(row).push_back(y);
```

I'm not sure if that's the correct syntax of how to approach that but I want that to be the final functionality. 
My goal is to create a 30x3 matrix with each index in the matrix being a vector of size 3

Comment: Do you set the size of the vectors before accessing them? If you, please post code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [2d Vector Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180146/2d-vector-initialization)

Comment: Are the sizes fixed and known at compile time (always 30 x 3 x 3)?

Comment: @Bob__ Yes they're always fixed

Comment: You could use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), then (e.g. something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/rzr5xzvb7)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> x(30, std::vector<std::vector<int>>(3, std::vector<int>(3)));
```

The constructor I am using takes `(std::size_t n, T t)` as in `n` elements of type `T`.

If you want to replace a *vector* in a given cell, you can use:

```
x[2][4] = {2, 7, 9};
```

Or you can replace an entire row of `3`like this:

```
x[1] = {{2, 7, 9}, {1, 1, 8}, {6, 2, 1}};
```

Comment: Would this also be able to handle pushing a separate `vector<int>` variable? My code will be generating random numbers, and I want to be able to fill a `vector<int>` with 3 numbers and pushing it into my matrix. for example `vector<int> y{2, 7, 9}` `vector<int> a{1, 2, 3}` `vector<int> b{3, 4, 5}` and `x[2].push_back(y)` `x[2].push_back(a)` `x[2].push_back(b)`

Comment: oh. i see why pushing back won't work. I think i can handle that tho by assignment instead

Answer (score 1):

use `{}` instead of `[]`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> x{
    {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}},
    {{5, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}, {3, 3, 3}}
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified more. I've edited my post to reflect the specifics of what I'm trying to do.